# Use the same bib file for BibTex and BibLaTex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am forced to use BibTex for my paper, because this is defined by the journal template. Till now, I used biblatex with the @online field for citing websites, which does not exist in bibtex. If I use the note-field for setting the url and date manually, this messes up my documents if compiled with biblatex. If I do not use the note-field, no url and date are displayed if compiled with bibtex, because this does not recognize these fields.

How can I use bibtex and biblatex for online references on the same bib-file without messing up the references?

Comment: Your write-up is not entirely clear. For one, having an entry type called `@online` is not a problem, *per se*, for BibTeX, as it'll use the fallback entry type `@misc` if it encounters an unknown entry type. Second, it's actually not BibTeX itself but the bibliography style, which *you* specify, which determines which entry types are recognized. Thus, do please tell us which bibliography style you employ under BibTeX. Finally, do please let us know if you use a citation management package (say, `natbib`) under BibTeX.

Comment: The field @online does result in the error "entry not style defined" if used in BibTex. So this does not work. The template uses the ACS style.

Comment: The `acs` bibliography style does not appear to be distributed with TeXLive, and it doesn't appear on the CTAN. Is it available online? Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure it's an *error message* that BibTeX emits when it encounters the entry type `@online`? Isn't it, rather, a *warning message*? Something like "Warning--entry type for [entry] isn't style-file defined"?

Comment: I can not give exact information about the style, since this is somehow encapsulated in the class files of the template. I just use the specified commands. Also, yes, it is a warning, but inside the text it appears an "[?]" instead of the correct cite.

Comment: It depends a bit on how many entries are involved and often you need them in both systems. You can setup something using biber sourcemaps or the biber tool-mode to convert the entries, but if this is just for one article and for a few entries, I would simply make a copy of the entries, give them a new key and change the fields. That is faster.

Comment: If you're geting `[? ]` instead of a proper citation call-out, that's usually a sign of either not running BibTeX after adding the associated `\cite` instruction (followed by two more LaTeX runs to fully resolve the argument of `\cite`) or of there being a typo in either the `\cite` instruction or in the entry in the bib file. Either way, the BibTeX log file (extension: .blg) should provide the information you need to resolve the matter appropriately.